# What could I have done to Chrome to make it impossible to add comments on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, status-norepro, comments, google-chrome

I suddenly find myself unable to add comments on Stack Overflow when I'm using Chrome version 9.0.597.98.

I have sufficient reputation to comment; I can comment when I log in using Internet Explorer 8; it works fine in Firefox 3.6.13, too.

What setting have I changed or what library am I missing to break this functionality?

Update:

I started the developer tools in Google Chrome and looked at the error logs.  Here are two errors that might be germane:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined - master.min.js
Failed to load resource - jquery.min.js
```

I'm all set - shift-F5 did the trick.  Thanks so much to all who answered.

Comment: testing. I'm using Chrome 9.0.597.102. edit: no repro.

Comment: It would help a lot if you described at what point in the process it breaks down?

Comment: I'm going to move this to SO because this functionality is appearing on all sites. For what it's worth they don't support beta versions officially, so see if you can reproduce this in Chrome 8.

Comment: I had a similar issue happen to me yesterday on SO in firefox. Suddenly I lost the ability to vote, comment, and view vote totals. In the error console I could see a couple of JS errors (`gauth` not defined or something similar to that). Clearing my browser cache fixed it. I assume some update must have happenned that was incompatible with a cached script file I already had.

Comment: Happened to me today right here on Meta - all JS related stuff stopped working and Chrome console showed some really bizarre errors.. pity I didn't copied them!

Comment: @Josh - Chrome 9.0.597.98 is the officially released version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try shift-F5.

Comment: On a windows system shift-F4 also does a good job.

Comment: This took care of it.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't do anything, it's temporary glitch that happened to me as well (and to others judging from the comments) as result of client side script error in one of the external resources.

If it happens again go to Tools --> JavaScript Console and copy the exact error so the moderators will have something to work with. :)

Unless it's permanent behavior that you're still having??